Javascript not seeming to be noticed by html file when button calls function, and not sure why
I'm new to JavaScript and html. I've been trying to figure out how this problem is coming up but it's not really consistent. Is there something I'm doing wrong that I'm not noticing?
--JavaScript--
    function e() {
        let consoleTestElement = document.getElementById("c");
        consoleTestElement.innerText = "e";
    }

--HTML--
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script defer src="index.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="e()" id="CalculationButton">Find Type Interactions</button>

        <p id="c">Stuff</p>

    </body>
    </html>

This is mainly for debugging purposes and this isn't the primary purpose of the website. But what is suppose to happen is that when the button is clicked, the "stuff" in the c paragraph just turns to "e".
Some things I've tried:

Putting the defer keyword in the script element
Setting a listener to the button through JavaScript with window.onload()
Putting the script element on the bottom of the page

Again, I'm new to this and I'm not sure what I'm missing
Edit: Some context I'm missing is that I'm trying to run this on a ASP.NET framework in visual studio. But I didn't think it was the problem originally because the code is minimal. The c# code runs like this
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    var app = builder.Build();

    //app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.Run();
}

with everything being ran in a wwwroot folder except the program.cs file. Which is in the parent folder the project is located in.

Any errors in the console? I'd take a guess that the JS file is not loaded because the path is wrong. But there is very little to go on here.

Welcome to web development! I tested your code in an online sandbox and it works as expected. I believe your issue has to do with the fact that the index.js path is not valid. Either move the index.js file to the same root directory/folder or change the path reference.

It's in the same folder of wwwroot. I updated the post expanding on this. I'm trying to use c# for the backend eventually but I've only set it up so I could get used to getting the front end figured out.

Never mind, I figured out what the problem was. Turns out having a const variable above the function that is outside of a function will cause problems. I'm not sure why, but commenting that out seems to fix the issue.

@TheEmeraldEnd were you trying to assign to the const in the function? If so, you cant do that.

@Phix It is something that I tried to do, but for some reason, the javascript script I was making didn't allow the variable to be defined outside of a function for some reason. I did a workaround where I just moved the variable to inside of a function.
